# Ad unit level vs App-level admob

Tags: android, admob, frequency

I am done making a wallpaper app the only problem before publishing is that what should be the cap for ad frequency. I am not able to understand the diff between Ad unit level and app unit level. Can somebody elaborate because I am not able to understand it from documentation. Please provide admob cap suggestion for a wallpaper app.
Recently, I read a person using 1 impression/2 minutes for both app level and unit level isn't, it too much?
Please elaborate it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not too much. You can set as 5 impression/minute which will help you in your earnings.Let me know which Ad unit you created Banner/Interestial/Reward?
If its banner than 5/minute , interestial 2/minute , for reward video 1 per minute.

Comment: its interestial and there is no ad cap for banner. But how do frequency cap works please explain

Comment: It mean it will hit ads displaying request. Then will display ads to app user. Suppose if you set it 5 impression/minute then it  will request to ads displaying 5 times and will display 5 times to users.

Comment: but would be the diff between app level and ad unit level?Sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: yes would differ but you should set to ad unit level not to app level. All points i told you it was regarding ad unit level.

Comment: I mean if I set 5/minute on ad unit level then it will show 5 impressions in 1 minute ?

Comment: But it would be too much the user will get irritated even when I show 2 impressions per minute

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer or vote up for my answer.

Comment: Sorry but it wasn't clear to me I will wait for sometime to get answer and then if didn't get the answer will mark your